# Why does OpenBSD's G++ make system headers default to C linkage?

Tags: gcc, boost, compiler-errors, header-files, openbsd

I am porting some code to OpenBSD 5.0 and I ran into this very strange problem.

My build settings use `-isystem /usr/local/include`. It is hard to remember but I believe I did that to avoid masses of compiler warnings from my use of `-Wall` on system types -- like BSD -- that install Boost to `/usr/local/include`. This seems to work great on FreeBSD.

So take the following program:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

Then build it with:

```
c++ -O2 -pipe -isystem /usr/local/include -std=c++98 -o test test.cxx
```

On OpenBSD I discovered that I get:

```
In file included from /usr/include/g++/string:46,
             from /usr/include/g++/stdexcept:44,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/array.hpp:35,
             from test.cxx:1:
/usr/include/g++/bits/stringfwd.h:48: error: template with C linkage
```

And it only gets worse from there.

I discovered that I can change the error messages by doing things such as:

```
#include <stdexcept>
```

But that only pushes the problem farther back. It is as if the compiler is wrapping every include file inside an `extern "C"` block.

So far, the only working method seems to be to change back to using `-I /usr/local/include` and accept the noise from `-Wall -W`.

The question is, why did OpenBSD do this? It has to be some kind of custom hack to GCC to treat system includes this way.

Comment: what version of gcc are you using ? As standard the version of gcc is older than the one on freebsd. I believe you can install a later version of it on openbsd. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently came across the same issue when working with a freestanding cross compiler.

It seems G++ will do this when targeting "old" systems as indicated here:

http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html#SEC9a

> On very old systems, some of the pre-defined system header directories get even more special treatment. GNU C++ considers code in headers found in those directories to be surrounded by an extern "C" block. There is no way to request this behavior with a #pragma, or from the command line.

Hope this may provide some insight to future travelers here.