# gcc -MDD with -isystem<include_path> wont add dependencies for "system" paths

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gnu

So I have the following setup (simplified version):

```
application/app1.hpp
application/app1.cpp
application/utils/utils1.hpp
application/utils/utils1.cpp
```

So when I compile app1.cpp I do so like this (this is a cut-down version of the compile):

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I application -isystem application/utils -MMD -MP -MF dep.d -c application/app1.cpp -o obj.o
```

Where I use -MDD to auto generate dependency information. I use -isystem to inhibit warnings from files in utils folder.

Note: that `utils` is a sub-module (i.e. a seperate project that compiles on its own). Therefore I don't want compile warnings/errors from that project. Therefore I am using `-isystem application/utils` to include folders. When you use isystem you don't get gcc warnings - which is great :)

However I just discovered that this is also the reason I am not getting complete depenecy outputs. Files included in the `isystem` directories are not added as dependecies in the gcc generated dep.d file.

So it seems I can either ignore the warnings from utils but not get depenency generation for it OR I can get the dependency output but not ignore the warnings.

I really want both:

- No warnings from utils
- Dependencies from utils folder (via gcc's -MMD)

Is that possible to get both behaviours somehow?

Some ideas of mine:

- I was thinking of somehow running the dependency pre-processor part on its own first and then the compile... but I did not see a way to do that
- Force include folders in the MMD part. I found that I can include specific files with `-include` but not folders and I don't have a list of files :(

Comment: You're going to end up with several portability problems. The `-isystem` behavior gets overloaded a lot on different operating systems. I ran into a BSD (OpenBSD maybe?) a while ago where all `-isystem` headers were automatically wrapped in `extern "C"` blocks. That was a problem for Boost.

Comment: Yeah, watch out for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775583/why-does-openbsds-g-make-system-headers-default-to-c-linkage

Comment: @ZanLynx thanks for the heads up on that one :) . For the moment I am happy that our environment is a controlled one (ubuntu linux only) for building.

Answer (score 0):

I just found something that could work, but I am not sure how efficient it is. I found the -E gcc option which replaces -c (compile) with preprocess only). So I could do:

1. Generate the dependency info:

   `g++ -I application -I application/utils -E application/app1.cpp -o /dev/null -MMD -MP -MF dep.d`
2. Compile the file with minimal warnings:

   `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I application -isystem application/utils -c application/app1.cpp -o obj.o`

This will mean that the preprocessor runs twice - not sure how much work that is... but it seems to run pretty quickly compared to the compile phase.

If there is further ideas I am still very much open to them... I won't mark this answer for a while incase someone has a better idea...